# Is there a maven plugin to install the project?

Tags: maven, plugins, installation

I'm new with Maven, I just finished to read the Sonatype guide and I'm very satisfied by the functions that maven makes available. I created an application distribution (.zip) package and I would like to know if there is a manner to use maven as an installer.
I don't mean the installation that maven does into the local repository, what I mean is explained by the following example:

I've a folder with a jar file, an .sql script, a /lib and obviously a pom.xml file.
I would like that maven installs this project for me when I execute the "mvn" command.
So maven should:
    - Copy the jar file in the ${TOMCAT_HOME}\webapps directory. 
    - Execute the sql script on the postgresql database
    - Copy the \lib directory in c:\myLibs 
    - etc etc
During this process it should also make some checks (example TOMCAT_HOME is set on the system? Postgres is turned on? etc.) and ask to the user some parameter (example "The installation will reset the database do you want to continue?" or "Please insert the database password: ".

Is there a maven plugin that helps to do this? If not is there an application alike maven specialized to create "installer" ? Is it a standard, widespread application?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

- Try: 
  [mvn deploy](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html).

Add to your pom

```
 <distributionManagement>
                <repository>
                        <id>sonatype.internal</id>
                        <name>Internal Release Repository</name>
                        <url>http://sonatypeAddress:sonatypePort/context</url>
                </repository>
 </distributionManagement>
```

Plugins section:

```
              <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                                <tag>${build.tag}</tag>
                                <username>${scm.username}</username>
                                <password>${scm.password}</password>
                        </configuration>
               </plugin>
```

- [antrun plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/)  - and make what you want.

  ```
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>1.7</version>
              <dependencies>
                  ...
              </dependencies>
              <executions>                    

                  <execution>
                      <id>install</id>
                      <phase>install</phase>
                      <configuration>
                          <target>
                                                       <delete dir="mylocalization" />
                              <copy file="target/out/my.jar" tofile="mylocalication" />

                              <copy todir="mylocalization/doc">
                                  <fileset dir="target/doc" />
                              </copy>
                              <copy todir="mylocalization/somethingMore">
                                  <fileset dir="target/more">
                                      <include name="a.txt" />
                                      <include name="b*.txt" />
                                  </fileset>
                              </copy>


                          </target>
                      </configuration>
                      <goals>
                          <goal>run</goal>
                      </goals>
                  </execution>

              </executions>
          </plugin>
  ```
- See also [maven-wagon](http://mojo.codehaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/usage.html)